# WKWebView wait for DOM rendering before triggering native code

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

I have a hybrid iOS app which contains a `WKWebView`, and I have a JavaScript function `callNative` can call Objective C native code in the main thread.

In my JavaScript, I have the following structure

```
modifyDOM(); // e.g. .show(), and .hide() stuff
callNative('animateWKWebViewFrame');
```

For some reason, `animateWKWebViewFrame` (native code) is called *before* `modifyDOM` completes and is fully rendered. (This causes a visual glitch.)

How can I force full rendering of DOM modifications before calling native code?

Comment: Can you show us some part of the `modifyDOM()` method? You mention that it does not contain any animations - maybe you are mistaken... have you tried adding log or alert statements in between `modifyDOM()` and `callNative` and maybe on at the end of the actual implementation of `modifyDOM()`!?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using jQuery because of your comment saying `modifyDOM` calls `show()` and `hide()`. If that is the case, then you should rely on the `complete` parameter to provide a function that will, in turn, make the call to your native code.

The relevant documentation is here :
http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete
http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete

And finally, here is some sample code :

```
function modifyDOM()
{
  someElement.show(400, function() {callNative('animateWKWebViewFrame');});
}
```

Comment: Animations are instant. They should complete immediately.

Comment: Then you may replace the duration of 400 by 0 in the code sample I provided and give it a try. If it doesn't solve your glitch, then maybe you could provide more details on both the glitch that occurs and the way you take the measurements to animate the WebView frame.

Comment: Considering you aren't providing any new information to solve your problem, here is another blind shot. I am guessing your changes impact the size of your content and that the measurements you are extracting to animate the frame of your WebView are wrong because rendering isn't over. If that is the case, make sure you are retrieving the size of the content using the getComputedStyle function as documented here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

How about make a another callback for detecting modifyDOM() function?

```
// alloc webview
    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [theConfiguration.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];
    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) configuration:theConfiguration];
```

Once your modifyDOM() function is finished you call "interOp" call back and then you can callback initiate() with whatever want and call animateWKWebViewFrame

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {

    NSDictionary *sentData = (NSDictionary*)message.body;
    NSString* command = sentData[@"command"];

    LOG(@"[userContentController] command(%@)", command);

    if ( [command isEqualToString:@"DOMReady"] ) {
        // defining a JavaScript function
        NSString *jsFunctionText = @"Initiate({"
                                    "command:animateWKWebViewFrame"
                                    "});";
        [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:jsFunctionText completionHandler:^(id object, NSError * err) {
            if ( err ) {
                LOG(@"[evaluateJavaScript] error(%@)", err);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure your method works. When your write "Once your modifyDOM() function is finished...", the problem is that JavaScript-land may think that `modifyDOM()` is finished executing when actually in rendering-land stuff is still in the pipeline.